# Hollow planet with artistic community under attack

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Inspired by this question [Novel about utopian society vs. authoritarian society](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204895/novel-about-utopian-society-vs-authoritarian-society). I'm seeking a story in a very similar vein to the Starhawk and Pat Murphy stories referenced. I read the novella or long(ish) short story in the mid nineties but it could have been published earlier.

As mentioned it's very similar in having an artistic community fighting back against brutal occupiers by using non lethal methods. However it's set in a far future galaxy, the artists live in a hollow world and the occupiers are slowly spreading out from the spaceport.

The artists spend a lot of time debating with the head of the invaders, but at night (artificial) they're scurrying about doing minor sabotage.

Several months ago on another site I speculated this might be an early Dorsai story titled "Amanda Morgan". I've since then managed a look at that story and it isn't the one I'm looking for.

Update

A further blurred memory, possible title is something like :-"Rocaanes world"
"Rohanas world"
"Rogains world"
Or similar!

Comment: *Rocannon's World* by Ursula Le Guin? It's not a match for this book though.

Comment: That's maybe why it sticks in my brain, it's a book title SIMILAR to the ones I listed.

Comment: Reagan's world? Grrrr at memory!

Comment: This search for ["R.*world.*"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=world&C=AND&USE_2=title_title&O_2=starts_with&TERM_2=r&USE_3=title_ttype&O_3=exact&TERM_3=SHORTFICTION&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title) doesn't look very promising:

Comment: It's possible that the 'R' is instead the initial of the name of the main protagonist, in which case  I've had a memory failure - sorry

Comment: Fred Saberhagen's "The Smile" (Algol Magazine, 1977) is about resistance from artists underground, but it isn't this story.

Comment: If it was an anarchists community, and not in the far future, and not underground, it could be Distress by Greg Egan. Could you have mixed up different element from different books?

Comment: Nah, I've got 'Distress' on my shelves - not the story I'm seeking